# Given two complex numbers that are adjacent vertices of a regular octagon, find the third vertex adjacent to the second

Tags: complex-numbers

I am new to complex numbers and I want help in this problem :

Let $ z_1,\  z_2 $ be two complex numbers, that are adjacent vertices of a regular octagon. Then what represents third vertex, $ z_3 $, adjacent to the second vertex $ z_2 $ ?

Assuming $ z_3 \ne z_1 $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know two things about $z_3$:

1. All sides of a regulat octagon have the same length, so $|z_3 - z_2| = |z_2 - z_1|$.
2. The angle between consecutive side of a regular octagon is $\pi/4$, so $\arg(z_3-z_2) = \arg(z_2 - z_1) \pm \pi/4$.

From these two facts you can find an expression for $z_3-z_2$ and hence an expression for $z_3$ (actually, two alternative expressions for $z_3$ since there are two solutions to the problem).